# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_product`)

Tags: laravel-5.8

Look at  my codes

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->body = $request->body;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->categories()->attach($request->category);
    $image = $request->image;
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('images/products'), $filename);
    $product->image = $image;

    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values (1, ?), (2, ?))

But I select a category of product already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before

> $product->categories()->attach($request->category);

Write,

`$product->save();`

This will insert the record in the database, and will return the last insert id. Then this will be used to be inserted into your pivot table.